# Java: How do I get a variable from the second method to work in the third method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

**HOMEWORK BACKGROUND**

I'm writing a java program for my class in which:

1. An array of 10 random numbers between 1 and 100 are generated
2. The application will pass the array to a calculated average method and then return the calculated average method to the main method
3. The array and the average value in the array will be passed to a count below method in which all numbers less than the average will be counted and the number of integers that are < average will be returned and displayed in the main method.

This is my beginner java class, so I'm not the best with java yet. I've been programming for about a month and a half.

**TL;DR:** My problem is I can't get the average variable in the second method to work in the third method in order to do the computation.

In the third method, I've tried calling the other method like: 
`calcAverage(int [] array))`
and
`public static double countBelow (int[] array, calcAverage(array))`

**EDITED:**

```
// main method
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    final int ARRAY_LENGTH = 10;

    //array object is created
    int array[] = new int [ARRAY_LENGTH];

    //for loop that loops through the array
    for (int rand = 0; rand < array.length; rand++)
    {
        // random number generator from 1-100
        array[rand] = (int)(Math.random()*100);

    }//end of loop

    //for loop that loops through the array
    for (int rand = 0; rand < array.length; rand++)
    {
        // prints random numbers to the screen
        System.out.printf("Numbers: %d \n", array[rand]);

    } //end of for loop


    //passing the array to the second method
    calcAverage(array);

    //prints out average
    System.out.print("Average is:");
    System.out.println (calcAverage(array));

    //passing array to the third method
     countBelow(calcAverage(array));


} // end of main method

    //declaring second method for calculating average
    public static double calcAverage(int[] array)
    {

        //declaring variables for the sum and average
        double sum = 0;
        double average = 0;

        //for loop that loops through the array
        for (int rand = 0; rand < array.length; rand++)
        {
            //computes the sum of the random numbers from first method
            sum += array[rand];
        }

        //computes average
        average = (sum / array.length);

        //returns average to main method
        return average;


    } //end of second method


    //start of third method
    public static int countBelow (int[] array, double average)
    {
        int scoresBelow = 0;


        //for loop that loops through the array
        for (int rand = 0; rand < array.length; rand++)
        {


            if (array[rand] < average)
            {
                scoresBelow ++;
            }

            else {}

        }

        return scoresBelow;


    }



}//end of class ArrayTest
```

I get the error message:

error: method countBelow in class ArrayTest cannot be applied to given types;
         countBelow(calcAverage(array));
         ^
  required: int[],double
  found: double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: You can't use a method call as a parameter definition. Call the methods from you main method (for example).

Comment: And in the third method you create a local variable ```scoresBelow``` but it is inside of a ```for loop``` so you cant return it

Comment: Thanks, edited the scoresBelow variable and declared it before the **for loop**

Comment: With editing what people suggested:
I now get this 

**error: method countBelow in class ArrayTest cannot be applied to given types;
   countBelow(array);
   ^
  required: int[],double
  found: int[]
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length**

Comment: Aside: `average = (sum / 10);` should use `array.length` instead of 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `countBelow` method seems to have two parameter:
`int[] array` and the result of `calcAverage(array)`,
so the signature should be:

```
public static int countBelow(int[] array, double average) {
    // ...
}
```

I assume you want to pass the result of `calcAverage(array)` to this method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = ...
    int count = countBelow(array, calcAverage(array));
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As others mentioned, your `countBelow` method should return a natural number.

---

**Edit2:**

> error: method countBelow in class ArrayTest cannot be applied to given types; countBelow(calcAverage(array)); ^ required: int[],double found: double reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 1 error

Seems like you mismatched the number of parameters now. If you define 2 (array & average), you need to call it with 2.

```
//passing array to the third method
countBelow(array, calcAverage(array));
```

Note that the array needs to be passed to each method individually. Passing the array to `calcAverage` does not pass it automatically to the `countBelow` method.

Comment: Thank you! This helped immensely, I am able to compile now.

Answer (score 0):

You either needs to compute the average in the main method, and pass it to `countBelow`, or compute it in `countBelow`:

**First version** — Compute before and pass to `countBelow`

```
// You pass the average already computed as a double argument:
public static double countBelow (int[] array, double average) {
    // Do what you must do...
}

// In the main method:
final int[] array = ...;
final double average = calcAverage(array);
countBelow(array, average);
```

**Second version** — Compute the average directly in `countBelow`

```
// You only pass the array:
public static double countBelow(int[] array) {
    // You compute the average here:
    final double average = calcAverage(array);

    // Do what you must do...
}

// In the main method:
final int[] array = ...;
countBelow(array);
```